# CSS : text is moving up while hover

Tags: html, css

I am making a navigation menu.

When I hover on the menu text then there is a border bottom appears but along with it the text is moving up side.

```css
.b-b {
  border-bottom: thin #cadadd solid;
}

.row_height {
  height: 46px;
}

.menu_div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 46px;
}

.menu_div span {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 3px;
}

.menu_div:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #353f51;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row b-b row_height">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="menu_div">
      <span>Home</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

that's because you've got a 2px border on hover. Add this to fix this:

```
.menu_div {
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set an invisible bottom border for the element `.menu_div` like this:

```
.menu_div{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    height:46px;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

```css
.b-b {
  border-bottom: thin #cadadd solid;
}

.row_height {
  height: 46px;
}

.menu_div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 46px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

.menu_div span {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 3px;
}

.menu_div:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #353f51;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row b-b row_height">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="menu_div">
      <span>Home</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```